# mongoimport --db new_Books_DB --collection New_Book_Data --file books.json; Uncaught: SyntaxError: Missing semicolon

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

data set is not imported from the terminal and getting an error show below

test> mongoimport --db new_Books_DB --collection New_Book_Data --file books.json;
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:14)

> 1 | mongoimport --db new_Books_DB --collection New_Book_Data --file books.json;
> |               ^
> 2 |

test>

I am trying to import the json file present in my download directory where as i am changing my directory first and landed on the same directory where my json file is present and the command

```
mongoimport --db new_Books_DB --collection New_Book_Data --file books.json;
```

But not import the json file.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute mongoimport from OS command line.

If you are trying to run this utility from mongosh - MongoDB shell, it will not work since this needs to execute from the command line of OS.

Two things - the prompt "test>" and the semicolon at the end of the command, indicate that you are in Mongo shell. Please quit and come out of it and then try the same command you have provided in this post, still please do not give semicolon at the end.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).